# Loading in Lua Modules via Require (TLC)

Tags: lua

I'm trying to use https://github.com/aptiva/TLC

I try:

```
$ echo $LUA_PATH; echo "====="; find .; echo "====="; luajit-2.0.0-beta10 examples/window.lua
```

I get:

```
?;?.lua;./?/init.lua
=====
.
./examples
./examples/talkingcomputer.lua
./examples/window.lua
./lst
./objc
./objc/BridgeSupport.lua
./objc/dispatch.lua
./objc/init.lua
./README.md
=====
luajit-2.0.0-beta10: error loading module 'objc' from file 'objc':
        cannot read objc: Is a directory
stack traceback:
        [C]: ?
        [C]: in function 'require'
        examples/window.lua:5: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

My question: what am I doing wrong? How do I load in the objc module?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `./?/init.lua` to `LUA_PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

Some further explanation on why the accepted solution works.

When a module is required, Lua uses environment variable **LUA_PATH** to find the location of the required module. The special symbol `'?'` is a wildcard that matches any string, thus when `require("module")` and `LUA_PATH="?;./?.lua"`, Lua will search for '*module*' and '*module.lua*' in the current directory.

In the question above LUA_PATH was originally defined as:

```
LUA_PATH="?;?.lua;"
```

Once the solution was posted, the user added `./?/init.lua` at the end of LUA_PATH, however it didn't work. The reason why it didn't work was that when Lua tries to solve `require('objc')` *objc* matches the first entry in LUA_PATH (?), and *objc* is a directory, thus the error.

The solution is to add `./?/init.lua` at the beginning of LUA_PATH:

```
LUA_PATH="./?/init.lua;?.lua;?;"
```

With regard to LUA_PATH, it's important to notice that unlike environment variable PATH, directories are separated by semicolon (";"). Another way of specifying what directories to search from, it's using Lua variable `package.path` (inside a Lua file):

```
package.path = "./?/init.lua;"..package.path
local objc = require("objc")
```